# Do I need to make my website compatible with IE8 and earlier?

Tags: website-design

I'm currently in the design/start stage of my personal website, the books I'm reading point out that IE8 practically doesn't support anything with new websites, should I make a IE8 version of my website or is that not a problem due to limited use?

Comment: Does your user base use IE8? If not, no. Check with your users, or look at traffic metrics.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey Thanks for the tip, will look at that! I will probably not be making a IE8 version unless I find out a lot of people use it to access my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to make my website compatible with IE8 and earlier?

Do a significant number of users of your web site use IE8 or earlier and would they be unwilling to upgrade to use your site?

If so, then yes.

Otherwise, no.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I will look into that!  My guess is no, since it is a personal site I probably won't get a lot of traffic period.  I'm not at 15 rep so I can't up vote your post but I will once I get there!

Answer (score 2):

When IE8 makes up 0.3% (one third of one percent) of internet browsers that hit your site, I'd say it's probably not worth spending that much effort on:

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: While the advice given by Baronz is sound, it's important to note that the statistics on the linked pages are from a biased sample. According to the page, "_The following figures are based on W3Schools' **users**_" (emphasis added). The user base of W3Schools -- programmers, students, web developers, etc. -- is likely not representative of the population at large. Don't use it as a replacement for your own traffic metrics and real user statistics (as @evil-closet-monkey noted)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will take that into account!  I'm not at 15 rep yet so can't upvote your post but I will when I get there!

Comment: @DylanKnowles Good advice!